# How to get the HTTP/REST Method Type of a testStep from groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui, rest-assured

I am working an a bulk update utility for large sets of SoapUI Projects. 
The update will depend upon what type of REST method each Test Step is for example: POST,GET,PUT

Right now I only care about REST type test steps, so I am filtering them by :

```
    if (testStep.config.type == "restrequest") {
        log.info "REST type test step found! " 
     }
```

But, is there a way to know what method the testStep is using ? 
I specially care about POST methods.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the testSteps of type REST you can use [`getRestMethod()`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/RestTestRequestStep.html#getRestMethod()) to get [`RestMethod`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/RestMethod.html) and then [`getMethod()`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/rest/RestMethod.html#getMethod()) on it:

```
if (testStep.config.type == "restrequest") {
     log.info "REST type test step found! " 
     log.info "Method type ${ts.getRestMethod().getMethod()}"
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks :)